# how can i add buttons to my navigation controller toolbar,so that i can see them in all views

Tags: iphone, toolbar, button

I AM HAVING nav controller and in main view.nib i added two buttons on to tool bar and i should view these in next views also,but iam not able to see right now those in next view ,
where i hav to add these so i can see these buttons or access in any view ....

any help appreciated...

Answer (score 3):

Quick and easy way is to set the toolbar items for new view controller, before you push it.

```
// Assuming self.toolbarItems is already set.
UIViewController *newViewController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

[newViewController setToolbarItems:self.toolbarItems];

[self.navigationController newViewController animated:YES];
```

If you're finding applying this method before each pushing tedious, then you can subclass all your UIViewController implementations, and have it's toolbar be set, once and for all. :)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set the toolbarItems property of each view.

> When displayed, this toolbar obtains
>   its current set of items from the
>   toolbarItems property of the active
>   view controller. When the active view
>   controller changes, the navigation
>   controller updates the toolbar items
>   to match the new view controller,
>   animating the new items into position
>   when appropriate.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html