# How to preserve a navigation toolbar across views for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247422/how-can-i-add-buttons-to-my-navigation-controller-toolbar-so-that-i-can-see-them) [kind of] asks, how can I setup some toolbar items in my `MainWindow.xib` and have those items present when I use the `UINavigationController` `pushViewController:animated:`.

For example, my application has:

- `MainWindow.xib`, which contains a `UINavigationController` with navigation bar and a toolbar.
- `AViewController.xib`, which just contains a `UITableView`.

At some point, our user presses a toolbar button and the associated action performs:

```
- (void)someAction {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[AViewController alloc] 
        initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] 
      animated:YES];
}
```

When the new view gets pushed, it contains a blank toolbar, instead of the toolbar with the same items as before. What's the preferred method for keeping them the same? I feel like I'm just missing something simple! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've figured out a way around this, but I'm interested if others have input, so I will wait on answering it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have one of my classes adopt the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol and implement the `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` method like this,

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [viewController setToolbarItems:toolbarItems animated:NO];
}
```

where I create and store `toolbarItems` in the delegate class. One of the likely candidates for being the delegate is the application delegate class as it is most probable place where you will instantiate the navigation controller.

Comment: Very cool. Added `<UINavigationControllerDelegate>` to my application delegate and the function above to that delegate code. Presto.

Only other trick I needed, since I specify the items in the `.xib` was to put an if statement in `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated` to determine if the toolbar had items or not. When it's first called, it does not so it will empty out the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up switching to Deepak's answer, but I also thought I would provide this in case it helps someone (or if people want to provide feedback).

In my `showAction` method defined above, I refactored it to this:

```
- (void)someAction {
    AViewController *av = [[AViewController alloc]
        initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [av setToolbarItems:[[self.navigationController toolbar] items]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:av animated:YES];
}
```